# Find items with extra values in MongoDB Aggregation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I need to get a list of items in the collection. Normally I use:

```
Transaction.find()
```

Result:

```
[
  {
    _id: 1283468346827863477,
    firstName: 'alex',
    amount: 23912
  },
  {
    _id: 1283468346827863477,
    firstName: 'alex',
    amount: 46456
  },
  // ...
]
```

But I need to get more values from the database. I do not know how to use aggregation.
I need this data:

```
{
  income: <Sum of amount>,
  items: [
    {
        _id: 1283468346827863477,
      firstName: 'alex',
      amount: 23912
    },
    {
        _id: 1283468346827863477,
      firstName: 'alex',
      amount: 46456
    },
    // ...
  ]
}
```

I wrote this code but the output is not what I expect:

```
const trxs = await Transaction.aggregate([
    {
      $match: findObj,
    },

    {
      $group: {
        _id: null,
        total: {
          $sum: '$amount',
        },
      },
    },
  ]);
```

I also need all the defined collection's fields.

Comment: Add `items: {$push: "$$ROOT"}` to total field

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Thank you so much.